# How do I display multiple Radio Button outputs back to the user in one Message Box?

Tags: c#

Whenever I select multiple pizza toppings I get the application to return the toppings I selected, but in different message boxes.

I am expecting the application to return all of the selected pizza toppings through one message box.

```
        if(cheeseCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You selected Cheese.",
                "Selected Topping",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);

        }

        if (mushroomCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You selected mushroom.",
                "Selected Topping",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }


        if (bellPepperCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You selected Bell Pepper.",
                "Selected Topping",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

        if (pepperoniCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You selected Pepperoni.",
                "Selected Topping",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You only want to show the Message Box *once*, at the end of checking *all* of the possible toppings. Change your if statements to *build* the list of chosen items, then afterwards use that listing to display the full message.

```
List<string> selectedToppings = new List<string>();

if (cheeseCheckBox.Checked) {
    selectedToppings.Add("Cheese");
}

if (mushroomCheckBox.Checked) {
    selectedToppings.Add("mushroom");
}

// etc...

if (selectedToppings.Any()) {
   // only show the message box if you have at least one selected.
   // feel free to customize this behavior

   var message = $"You selected: {string.Join(", ", selectedToppings)}";
   MessageBox.Show(message, "Selected Toppings", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```